# Destructor , Returning temp object

Tags: c++, object, destructor

I do not understand what is the problem in returning temp object. If I do not use destructor then everything is fine.
But with destructor it creates problem.coefficients for polynomial 1 and 2 are printed correctly.polynomial 3 also. But after addition coeff[1] and coeff[2] of polynomial 3 didn't give correct value.Can anyone help?

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

class poly{
public:
float* coeff;
int degree;
int arr_size;
/*default constructor*/
poly(){
    coeff = new float [11];
    arr_size = 10;
    for(int j=0;j<=arr_size;j++)
        coeff[j] = 10;
    cout << "Object created using default constructor..." << endl;
}

 poly(poly &p){
    arr_size = p.arr_size;
    coeff = new float[arr_size+1];
    for(int j=0;j<=arr_size;j++)
        coeff[j] = p.coeff[j];
    cout << "Copy constructor called......"<<endl;
}

~poly(){
    if(coeff){
        delete [] coeff;
        coeff = NULL;
        cout << "Destructor Msg:: Allocation free!!" << endl;
    }
}

void show();
void setCoeff();
poly operator+ (poly);};
 /*Show all coefficiens of a ploynomial*/
 void poly :: show(){
 for(int j=0; j<=arr_size; j++)
    cout << "coeff[" << j <<"]:\t"<< coeff[j]<< endl;
}



   /*To set a specific coefficient in the polynomial*/
 void poly :: setCoeff(){
 int i;
 again: cout << "Enter degree of coefficient you want to set: ";
 cin >> i;
 if(i>arr_size || i<0){
     cout << "!! Enter appropriate value." << endl;
    goto again;
}
cout << "Enter new value: ";
cin >> coeff[i];
}

poly poly :: operator+ (poly p){
poly temp;
for(int i=0;i<=arr_size;i++)
    temp.coeff[i] = coeff[i] + p.coeff[i];
    return temp; //I think Problem in this line 
 } 





int main(){
    cout << "***********  WELCOME  ***********" << endl;
    poly p[3];
    p[2] = p[0] + p[1];
    p[2].show();
    cout << "Thank You!!!" << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your problem statement is "didn't give correct value". That is not a good problem statement.

Comment: You only have to read until `float* coeff;` to be able to guess the problem. Using a `std::vector<float>` would solve it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You did not define an assignment operator, so when you do `p[2] = p[0] + p[1]`, the default assignment operator is used, which assigns `p[2].coeff` to point to the same array as the `coeff` of the temporary object created by the addition.

So when the temporary object is destroyed, its destructor deletes the array and `p[2].coeff` is now an invalid pointer. Therefore accessing it will lead to undefined behaviour.

Also a copy constructor should take a `const` reference as its argument.

Comment: So what's the solution.

Comment: @user5347919 The solution is to define an assignment operator and a proper copy constructor (i.e. add a `const` to the parameter).

Answer (score 0):

What if using "bool temp" in class poly?

```
poly poly :: operator+ (poly p){
poly* buffer = new poly();
buffer->temp = true;
for(int i=0;i<=arr_size;i++)
    temp.coeff[i] = coeff[i] + p.coeff[i];
if (p.temp == true)
    delete &p;
return buffer;
}
```

Comment: I had exactly same problem. and this idea makes me help